# Multiple-page code posting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some other code sites, such as [sololearn.com](http://sololearn.com), implement (admittedly fairly limited) multi-page solutions for code posting. So, for example, it is possible to split the HTML off from the CSS off from the JS in a web coding situation.

Given that many programs are multifaceted these days, and often involve various units and files, would something be gained by moving Stack Exchange from the one-page solution it currently favours and on to a multi-page solution?

Given also the prominent use of Plunker and JSFiddle and similar which also implement these features and seem to be used partly *because* they implement these features, albeit with a more limited remit, what do people feel are the pros and cons of implementing this feature?

*note to address previous rolledback edit: Code Snippets do not seem to fully fit this remit, but only partially, unless someone can explain otherwise

Comment: I added the tag because that's the feature you're writing about. If you're not asking solely about HTML/CSS/JavaScript then it's not 100% clear.

Comment: I said 'for example' before I mentioned HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I'd guess that a question with code that is too big for a snippet and needs multiple pages is probably going to be too broad (I don't frequent any of the programming sites that much so maybe I'm wrong, but that's my assumption)

Comment: A question about a problem in code never needs multiple pages. If it does the OP simply didn't try hard enough to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the few cases where it is needed (game development or certain question that involve large datasets) there are enough workarounds available and **NOT** having such feature really puts the pressure on asking a well formed and to the point question that can be answered. The SE Network is not meant to be a project collaboration platform. You have listed those in your question.